# Sort numpy array according to tags

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I am a new beginner in python/numpy/scipy. I have a sequence of measured numbers whose values run between 41 and 48 let s say. The sequence is supposed to be periodical and contains values that peaks above 44. It typically consist in 2 values above 44, then 25 values under, then 4 values above 44 and then 25 value under, and the sequence repeat itself indefinitely. For the moment, I put the whole sequence in a numpy array, `sequence_np[k]` , here are example of values of a typical measurement for k = 0 to k = 100:

```
Out[203]:
array([ 380.01873779,   50.55169296,   42.77656174,   42.65046692,
     42.43999863,   42.40890503,   42.2605629 ,   42.10827637,
     42.1680069 ,   42.11898422,   42.12486267,   42.04322433,
     42.0951767 ,   41.91516495,   42.06472015,   41.93815613,
     41.89348221,   41.94158936,   41.89970016,   41.9259491 ,
     41.81912231,   41.86272049,   41.75209045,   41.80240631,
     41.76036072,   45.26025391,   46.82533646,   46.50036621,
     44.32830048,   41.76332855,   41.78057098,   41.67221069,
     41.64173889,   41.65129471,   41.61840439,   41.69548798,
     41.67128372,   41.62164307,   41.44159698,   41.66975021,
     41.57759857,   41.61584091,   41.49560165,   41.56158066,
     41.56072617,   41.67589951,   41.53749466,   41.40168762,
     41.61867142,   41.5602684 ,   41.50307083,   41.52831268,
     45.30022049,   48.27410507,   41.43214798,   41.47129059,
     41.51285934,   41.50564957,   41.51237106,   41.46631241,
     41.47317505,   41.51570129,   41.50091553,   41.43928528,
     41.4920578 ,   41.46780014,   41.40225983,   41.38835144,
     41.38163376,   41.4108696 ,   41.46929169,   41.36049652,
     41.50559998,   41.37825775,   41.51349258,   41.33029938,
     41.39609909,   41.4021492 ,   41.35882187,   44.03855896,
     47.99585342,   48.23322678,   44.07878113,   41.41098022,
     41.24314117,   41.35625839,   41.45568848,   41.24409866,
     41.36055756,   41.3132782 ,   41.46337891,   41.24599838,
     41.31368256,   41.22081375,   41.38015366,   41.34594345,
     41.31343842,   41.25972748,   41.36122131,   41.23865891,
     41.39728546], dtype=float32)
```

I would like to sort the array according to the values above 44 but would like a different list or array for:

- the values located between the two above 44 and the four above 44: I would call them value_A [i]
- the values located between the four above 44 and the two above 44: Value_B[i]

for i = 1 to N where N depends on the length of my sequence of number.
The sequence can start wherever, i.e not necessarily with two 44 values.

For example `value_A[0]` would start at k = 2 and finish at 25, i.e `value_A[0] = sequence_np[2:25]`:

```
Out[206]:
array([ 42.77656174,  42.65046692,  42.43999863,  42.40890503,
    42.2605629 ,  42.10827637,  42.1680069 ,  42.11898422,
    42.12486267,  42.04322433,  42.0951767 ,  41.91516495,
    42.06472015,  41.93815613,  41.89348221,  41.94158936,
    41.89970016,  41.9259491 ,  41.81912231,  41.86272049,
    41.75209045,  41.80240631,  41.76036072], dtype=float32)
```

and `value_B[0] = sequence_np[29:52]`:

```
Out[218]:
array([ 41.76332855,  41.78057098,  41.67221069,  41.64173889,
    41.65129471,  41.61840439,  41.69548798,  41.67128372,
    41.62164307,  41.44159698,  41.66975021,  41.57759857,
    41.61584091,  41.49560165,  41.56158066,  41.56072617,
    41.67589951,  41.53749466,  41.40168762,  41.61867142,
    41.5602684 ,  41.50307083,  41.52831268], dtype=float32)
```

and so on. For the moment, I define a boolean list, `IndexSequence`,  using the command:

`IndexSequence = sequence_np>44`

I got the following output:

```
Out[182]: array([ True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
   False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
   False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,
    True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
   False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
   False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,
   False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
   False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
   False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,
    True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
   False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
   False, False], dtype=bool)
```

So I manage to find values under 44 but do not manage to sort them.

Any ideas or link on how to proceed further to manage to sort out sequence_np according to the scheme I have explained above are welcomed.

Thanks in advance,

Greg

Comment: Could you post some sample input and expected output? It's hard to tell "the values located between the two above 44 and the four above 44" means. In any case, this doesn't seem like a sorting problem, more like simple partitioning.

Comment: If the period is fixed, you can reshape your data into a two dimension array, and then the following process will be simple. To get more advice, you need to post the data, and what's the result you want.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I edit my post with data. The sequence is not really periodical, because I might loose values between the "peaks". I am sure however, that the value that peaks above 44 will always be present. That s why I would like to use them as tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose your array is named `a`; then try

```py
starts=numpy.intersect1d(numpy.where(a<44)[0]+1,numpy.where(a>44)[0])
print(numpy.split(a,starts))
```

The first line identifies the indexes for which a[i-1]<44 and a[i]>44; the second splits the array at these indexes.

Comment: Hi, Ok that worked. did like this to separate the value under 44 to the value above: `starts = np.intersect1d(np.where(a<44)[0]+1,np.where(a>44)[0])
ASortert = np.split(a,starts)
starts_2 = np.intersect1d(np.where(a<44)[0],np.where(a>44)[0]+1)
ASortert_2 = np.split(a,starts_2)
starts_3 = np.union1d(starts,starts_2)
ASortert_3 = np.split(a,starts_3)`

Answer (score 0):

Using standard library:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby 
>>> groups = [list(g[1]) for g in groupby(a, lambda x: x > 44)]
>>> print groups

[[380.01874, 50.551693], [42.776562, 42.650467, 42.439999, 42.408905, 
42.260563, 42.108276, 42.168007, 42.118984, 42.124863, 42.043224, 
42.095177, 41.915165, 42.06472, 41.938156, 41.893482, 41.941589, 
41.8997, 41.925949, 41.819122, 41.86272, 41.75209, 41.802406, 41.760361], 
[45.260254, 46.825336, 46.500366, 44.3283], [41.763329, 41.780571, 
41.672211, 41.641739, 41.651295, 41.618404, 41.695488, 41.671284, 
41.621643, 41.441597, 41.66975, 41.577599, 41.615841, 41.495602, 
41.561581, 41.560726, 41.6759, 41.537495, 41.401688, 41.618671, 
41.560268, 41.503071, 41.528313], [45.30022, 48.274105], [41.432148, 
41.471291, 41.512859, 41.50565, 41.512371, 41.466312, 41.473175, 
41.515701, 41.500916, 41.439285, 41.492058, 41.4678, 41.40226, 
41.388351, 41.381634, 41.41087, 41.469292, 41.360497, 41.5056, 41.378258, 
41.513493, 41.330299, 41.396099, 41.402149, 41.358822], [44.038559, 
47.995853, 48.233227, 44.078781], [41.41098, 41.243141, 41.356258, 
41.455688, 41.244099, 41.360558, 41.313278, 41.463379, 41.245998, 
41.313683, 41.220814, 41.380154, 41.345943, 41.313438, 41.259727, 
41.361221, 41.238659, 41.397285]]
```

It is then straightforward to group this list into pairs if that's what you need:

```py
pairs = zip(*[iter(groups)] * 2)
```

The result would be a a list of 2-tuples, each one consisting of two lists (values greater than 44 and values less than 44).